# how to add multiple chart component to vue dashbaord using vue-chartjs

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

[image]Hello guys I am working on a dashboard using vue using components defined in a .vue file I'm wondering how can I implement the multiple chart type to a dash component like this image

Comment: Have you managed to add a single chart to a page? The vue-chartjs guide packs the chart into a component, just use the component multiple times, or use different components for different charts.

Comment: yes I have added a chart before

Comment: I think what cello may be asking is - what did you try? Your question doesn't share the code you tried to use.